# How to stop displaying angular tooltip on focus/click?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a field which on blur displays a tooltip. But I don't know why it also pops up when I click on the field. 
Here is the codepen example: http://codepen.io/Octtavius/pen/aZzyKw?editors=1010

Below is the code where I use angular bootstrap:

```
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" class='container'>


    <input type="text" 
         ng-controller="myPopoverCtrl"
         popover-template="myPopover.templateUrl" 
         popover-title="This is a popover" 
         popover-placement="bottom" 
         popover-is-open="myPopover.isOpen" 
         ng-blur="myPopover.open()" />

    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <h2 ng-bind="myPopover.data"/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="myPopover.close()">
            Close me!
        </button>
    </script>

</body>
```

Controller

```
app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller(
   'myPopoverCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      // query popover
      $scope.myPopover = {

      isOpen: false,

      templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',

      open: function open() {
        $scope.myPopover.isOpen = true;
        $scope.myPopover.data = 'Hello!';
      },

      close: function close() {
        $scope.myPopover.isOpen = false;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Can anyone help to understand why the tooltip popup on click when I set it to popup on blur/when leave the field???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because default trigger for popover is click: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover.
Try to disable it by `popover-trigger="none"`